# Can't get SSL with self signed CA to work in SQLYog

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have a server with mysql. I issued `grant all on *.* to 'user'@'%' require ssl;`, created ca, key and cert according to [this guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html). I'm not using client certs.

I copied `ca.pem` to a sandbox and connected to the database from this sandbox, using the command `mysql -u user -p -h 192.168.120.78 --ssl-ca=ca.pem` and it works like a charm. Without `--ssl-ca=ca.pem` it does not work, just as expected. Issuing `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'SSL_CIPHER';` confirms that encryption is working.

But when I'm trying to connect with SQLYog using the same ca it does not work. I get the error message

> Error No. 2026
>
> SSL connection error: self signed certificate

I'm using SQLYog 12.4.2

Comment: https://forums.webyog.com/forums/search/SSL+self+signed/

Comment: I'll take a look at thursday. Thanks. That's at least something I have not tried.

Comment: @Orphans That did it. Should I write an answer or do you want to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found this:

https://forums.webyog.com/forums/search/SSL+self+signed/

The CA-cert and server-cert cannot have the same common name, because this is a vulnerability for man in the middle attacks. Make sure that they differ. The CN for CA can be anything and the CN for server-certs should correspond to their IP or URL or similar.